# Receiving multipart POST data requests in PHP

Tags: php, http, mime, multipart, form-data

I want to receive the following `HTTP` request in `PHP:`

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data;boundary=main_boundary

--main_boundary
Content-type: text/xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<content>
Some content goes here
</content>

--main_boundary
Content-type: multipart/mixed;boundary=sub_boundary

  --sub_boundary
  Content-type: application/octet-stream

  File A contents

  --sub_boundary
  Content-type: application/octet-stream

  File B contents

  --sub_boundary

--main_boundary--
```

(Note: I have indented the sub-parts only to make it more readable for this post.)

I'm not very fluent in PHP and would like to get some help/pointers to figure out how to receive this kind of multipart form request in PHP code. I have once written some code where I received a standard HTML form and then I could access the form elements by using their name as index key in the `$HTTP_GET_VARS` array, but in this case there are no form element names, and the form data parts are not linear (i.e. sub parts = multilevel array).

Grateful for any help!

/Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$HTTP_GET_VARS`, `$HTTP_POST_VARS`, etc. is an obsolete notation, you should be using `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc.

Now, the file contents should be in the `$_FILES` global array, whereas, if there are no element names, I'm not sure about whether the rest of the content will show up in `$_POST`. Anyway, if `always_populate_raw_post_data` setting is true in *php.ini*, the data should be in `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`. Also, the whole request should show up when reading *php://input*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I guess the most decent solution would be to name the fields. Do you know what HTTP headers to use for this task?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it was helpful. Note: There are cases where $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is populated even if always_populate_raw_post_data is false.  This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should note:

“php://input allows you to read raw POST data. It is a less memory intensive alternative to $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and does not need any special php.ini directives. php://input is not available with enctype=”multipart/form-data”

From php manual... so it seems php://input is not available

Cannot comment yet but this is intened to complement pilsetnieks answer

Answer (score -2):

Uploadeds files will be accessible through the $_FILE global variable, other parameters will be accessible trough the $_GET global variable.

Comment: In PHP, while `multipart/form-data` will be accessible through the global `$_FILE`, rest of the data can be accessed through the global `$_POST`.